# Yammer autocomplete: No request after successful CORS preflight

Tags: axios, yammer

Ok, so I've been struggling for a while now...

I'm trying to make a `GET` request to this URL:

```
https://api.yammer.com/api/v1/autocomplete/ranked?prefix=oper&models=group:5,user:5,topic:5,
```

And I see the preflight succeeding:

[image]

The problem is that no `GET` request is made after the preflight. I'm using `axios` and doing something like:

```
axios({
    "https://api.yammer.com/api/v1/autocomplete/ranked?prefix=oper&models=group:5,user:5,topic:5",
    "get",
    headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
})
```

Why do you guys think the actual request is not being sent?

Comment: Try removing the "Content-Type": "application/json" part from your headers value n your axios call. It makes no sense to add a Content-Type header to a GET request.

Comment: Have you tried the JS SDK at https://developer.yammer.com/docs/js-sdk? This helps you setup the origins and make requests successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out to be a CORS problem.

Seems like Yammer changed something on their side and broke that endpoint. Touché

I had to solve it proxying my requests to that endpoint to my server and return the response from there.